# Including a column in from a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, moodle

Table: **ftf**

> id | name

Table: **Ftf_sessions**

> id | ftfid

Table: **User**

> id | username | firstname | lastname | email

Table: **Ftf_signups**

> id | sessionid | userid

Table: **Ftf_sessions_dates**

> id | sessionid | timestart | timefinish

Table: **Ftf_signups_status**

> id | signupid | statuscode

Hello,

From the tables above, I am trying to generate a report with the columns as follows:

> ftf.name | Ftf_sessions_dates.timestart | Ftf_sessions_dates.timefinish | User.firstname | User.lastname | User.username | User.email | Ftf_signups_status.statuscode

I wrote the following sql query which generates reports EXCEPT the column ftf.Name

I'd really appreciate if anyone could point me in correct direction. I couldn't add the column ftf.Name in the report.
Thanks.

**Updated the query and it works now thanks.**

```
select distinct
ftf_signups_status.statuscode as Status,
ftf.name as 'Facetoface Name',
concat(user.firstname, ' ', user.lastname) AS Name,
user.username as Username,
user.email as Email,

DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME( IFNULL( IF( ftf_sessions_dates.timestart <=> 0, NULL,
ftf_sessions_dates.timestart),
ftf_sessions_dates.timestart)), '%M %d, %Y' ) AS StartDate,

DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME( IFNULL( IF( ftf_sessions_dates.timefinish<=> 0, NULL,
ftf_sessions_dates.timefinish),
ftf_sessions_dates.timefinish)), '%M %d, %Y' ) AS FinishDate

from ftf_signups

inner join ftf_signups_status
on ftf_signups.id = ftf_signups_status.signupid

inner join user
on ftf_signups.userid = user.id

inner join ftf_sessions_dates
on ftf_signups.sessionid = ftf_sessions_dates.sessionid

inner join ftf_sessions
on ftf_signups.sessionid = ftf_sessions.id

inner join ftf
on ftf.id = ftf_sessions.facetoface
```